# Convert Isolated Storage Collections to SQL

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to update my app to use the new SQL DB that was added in Mango.  I have several collections currently stored in Isolated Storage.  I would love to be able to some how convert those into tables so I can then do some sort of back up and restore process (ultimate goal).

I was just wondering if there was any tool that did this conversion process.  If not, is there a tutorial that is out there that steps through this process?

If anyone has any other suggestions, I'd be game to hear them.

Comment: There is not currently an automatic conversion tool. You will just have to do it manually in code when your application starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no tool to do this in an automated fashion. Since there are no structural constraints in how you save your data you have to write your own code to read and write the persisted collection. Likewise you have to write your own code to prepare this data to be inserted into the database. If you provide more info on you file and DB structure we can give more specifics on what to do.

Comment: Joel - do you have any resources that I could read up on how to properly create (and edit) a DB on the phone?

Comment: Yep, WindowsPhoneGeek has quite a few http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/Windows-Phone-Mango-Local-Database-SQL-CE--Creating-the-Database